# If someone follows you, can they reply to your DM?

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

In the old days, the person couldn't reply to your DM if you didn't follow them.

I've heard this has changed to accommodate various companies to have a presence on social media.

Is that the case at all?

How could I know if the person can reply back to my DM, or would be prevented from doing so?

Comment: You can't even send a DM unless both of you are following each other

Comment: I sent a DM to a vendor without following them, a couple of minutes ago, directly on twitter.com.

Comment: Does it appear on your public Twitter timeline? If so, that's not a DM

Comment: No, DMs don't appear in public timeline.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a direct message to another Twitter user unless you both follow each other.

However, in October 2013, Twitter did allow for sending direct messages to accounts that did not follow you.

> Last month, Twitter quietly rolled out a new feature to give users the choice to receive private messages from any of their followers, but that option has now been removed.

[As of November 2013 it was made no longer available as a feature](http://thenextweb.com/twitter/2013/11/19/twitter-backtracks-removes-option-let-users-receive-direct-messages-follower/).

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. You can send a DM to people who follow you, but if you do not follow them, they cannot reply.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Twitter's documentation](https://support.twitter.com/groups/50-welcome-to-twitter/topics/204-the-basics/articles/119138-types-of-tweets-and-where-they-appear) someone only can send a DM to a person that follows him/her.

[image: Twitter's help]

Comment: So, they never fixed it?  I thought they made it possible for the big retailers to DM their customers with more ease.

Comment: If you take into account that DM are designed to permit for friends (that follow each other) to communicate, it is not a bug!!